# No sound and flash videos play super fast after daily update

Tags: 11.10, sound, grub2, flash

I just updated my 11.10 Ubuntu from the regular auto updater.
After I restarted my laptop I have no sound and the videos in YouTube (and other websites) play super fast.

Not sure if it has something to do with the case, but since last night I get **hd0 out of disk** error before the grub screen and on the login screen I have some delay before I can type my password. In the console I see errors like these: `status: {DRDY err}`.

I could say the errors have something to do with the sound problem and the flash player, but if this happened when I got the hd0 error, not now after the regular daily update.

Here is the update history log from `/var/log/apt/history.log`

```
Start-Date: 2012-04-03  10:04:39 
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.71'
Upgrade: python-aptdaemon.gtkwidgets:amd64 (0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1, 0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1.2), 
libvlc5:amd64 (2.0.1+git20120329+r134-0~r35~oneiric1, 2.0.1+git20120402+r146-0~r36~oneiric1), 
python-aptdaemon:amd64 (0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1, 0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1.2), 
vlc-nox:amd64 (2.0.1+git20120329+r134-0~r35~oneiric1, 2.0.1+git20120402+r146-0~r36~oneiric1), 
vlc-plugin-notify:amd64 (2.0.1+git20120329+r134-0~r35~oneiric1, 2.0.1+git20120402+r146-0~r36~oneiric1), 
aptdaemon:amd64 (0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1, 0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1.2), 
python-aptdaemon-gtk:amd64 (0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1, 0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1.2), 
vlc:amd64 (2.0.1+git20120329+r134-0~r35~oneiric1, 2.0.1+git20120402+r146-0~r36~oneiric1), 
aptdaemon-data:amd64 (0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1, 0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1.2), 
vlc-data:amd64 (2.0.1+git20120329+r134-0~r35~oneiric1, 2.0.1+git20120402+r146-0~r36~oneiric1),  
python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:amd64, 0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1,0.43+bzr697-0ubuntu1.2), 
libvlccore5:amd64 (2.0.1+git20120329+r134-0~r35~oneiric1, 2.0.1+git20120402+r146-0~r36~oneiric1), 
vlc-plugin-pulse:amd64 (2.0.1+git20120329+r134-0~r35~oneiric1, 2.0.1+git20120402+r146-0~r36~oneiric1)
End-Date: 2012-04-03  10:05:15
```

Comment: After some time looking at the update history log I think the problem is in VLC, because this is the only player I use and have on my laptop. Also I use the VLC plugin to display movies in the browser. Does it have something to do with the flash player? But in other side there is no sense, because I don't have system sound, so the problem cannot be only in VLC

Comment: does this have anything to do with it - http://www.shcherbyna.com/?p=946

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` this solved the issue. After I ran the pavucontrol in **Configuration** I have my video card listed. I disabled it as sound device which fixed the fast flash videos and the sound issue. Thanks! Make your comment an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The error is gone, no idea how that happened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the solution found on, [Flash video plays very fast without any sound](http://www.shcherbyna.com/?p=946), and that is to install Pulse Audio Volume Control [pavucontrol](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol]

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

now run pavucontrol,

```
pavucontrol
```

go to the **Configuration** tab and turn off the sound devices you don't use, most likely your video card is being listed as a sound device. Happy flash viewing!

Comment: Adding some SEO so people would be able to find this answer.
Sound not playing ubuntu, no sound ubuntu, fast play on ubuntu, why there's no sound? music isn't playing

Comment: Worked for me too, in 2016. Card is RSS 880 Audio [Radeon HD 4200 Series].

Answer (score 1):

`pavucontrol` works partially to me. By setting *Profile* to *off* just the video stream no more fast but audio still doesn't will output anymore.