# (Only) YouTube Videos automatically fast forward

Tags: sound, video, flash, youtube

I recently updated my Ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04 lts and there seems to be a problem while I'm playing YouTube videos they, for no reason, start to fastforward (audio and video). This does not happen with other programs or websites only in YouTube videos. It does not matter if they are in flash or in HTML 5 player this problem persists throughout

Comment: Which browser you are using, if its Firefox then try disabling addons and play them.

Comment: Some video playback tries to synchronise things to the sound card's clock.  Is there anything out of the ordinary about your audio set up, by any chance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No sound and flash videos play super fast after daily update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118459/no-sound-and-flash-videos-play-super-fast-after-daily-update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very brief time, Youtube recently exposed an experimental player on their site with fast and slow play capabilities, and this may be affecting the current player. If this is the case, it would help to clear your browser cookies.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I solved it this way; First install "PulseAudio Volume Control" if it is not installed yet;

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Now start "PulseAudio Volume Control" and go to the Configuration tab. Under "High definition Audio Controller" I had "Digital stereo (HDMI) Output" selected. I had to change that to "Off". I also had to change the build in audio profile from digital to analogue, otherwise I didn't hear anything.

edit: after the change above, it still happens sometimes. But I can use `pulseaudio -k` to restart pulseaudio. (`-k` will kill it, but it will restart automatically).

Answer (score 2):

If `pulseaudio -k` works temporarily, try [this guide](http://forum.pinguyos.com/Thread-How-to-Pulseaudio-and-Alsa) to replace pulseaudio with the alsa audio component. It's worked fine for me ever since. (Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I once wanted to listen to my computer through my wireless headset, so I changed the output in Settings>Sound to the USB Wireless Headset. But when it was unpluged it must have switched to the HDMI out sound instead of the normal speakers, when I switched back to the speakers the problem went away. Also in Settings>Sound>Applications, it says that YouTube is playing from ALSA Plugin, according to there website it is a audio extension type of thing. I don't know if ALSA has anything to do with it or if it is all on YouTubes side but whatever. Hope this helped.

Also I am using the web browser Chromium

Comment: This doesnt answer the question. Please add this as a comment. If you have the same problem, you can favorite this question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing to the audio device I had available, so if you are having problems with YouTube or any video,

1. Check you are connected to the right device. (you do it by looking at PulseAudio)
   if problem not solved
2. Check you have PulseAudio installed by trying to install it
   `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
3. Read above carefully